# Extracting compressed .gz and .bz2 s3 files automatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, boto3

I have a data dump from Wikipedia of about 30 files, each being about ~2.5 GB uncompressed size. I want to extract these files automatically, but as I understand I cannot use Lambda because it has file limitations.

I found another alternate solution of using SQS which will call EC2 instance, which I am working on. However, for that situation to work my script needs to read all zip files(.gz and .bz2) from S3 bucket and folders and extract them.

But on using zipfile module from python, I receive the following error:

`zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

Is there a solution to this?

This is my code:

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name="backupwikiscrape", key= 'raw/enwiki-20200920-pages-articles-multistream1.xml-p1p41242.bz2')
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())

z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
for filename in z.namelist():
    file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
        z.open(filename),
        Bucket='backupwikiextract',
        Key=f'{filename}'
    )
```

The above code doesn't seem to be able to extract the above formats. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your file is `bz2`, thus you should use [bz2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#module-bz2) python library.

To decompress your object:

```
decompressed_bytes = bz2.decompress(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use [smart_open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), it's much easier. It both handle gz and bz2 files.

```
from smart_open import open
import boto3

s3_session = boto3.Session()

with open(path_to_my_file, transport_params={'session': s3_session}) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            print(line)
```